# modifying array values using location in c++

Tags: c++

lets suppose I have an `unsigned int* val` and `unsigned char mat[24][8]`. Now the `val` stores the location of the variable `mat`. Is it possible to modify the bits in the mat variable using the location in `val`?

for ex:

`val = 0x00000001` and location of `val` in memory is `0x20004000`
the first element of `mat` is located at `0x00000001`.

Now i want to modify the value of `mat` at, say, 10,4. Is it possible to do this using C++?

Comment: If your question is C++, why the C tag?

Comment: @gareththegeek Huh, what are you talking about?

Comment: @crashmstr sorry, removed.

Comment: I think you need to read up on arrays.

Comment: If the different size of the dereferenced types of val (unsigned INT*) and mat (unsigned CHAR[][]) is inteded, please note that most of the answers ignore this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, unless either of the array members or the pointer target is `const`.

For example:

```
int array[3][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } };
int *p = &array[1][1];
*p = 42;

// array is now: { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 42 }, { 4, 5 } };
```

Comment: OP was using an unsigned char[][]

Comment: @gareththegeek I didn't write he wasn't!

Comment: OP was using a 2d-char Array and a unsigned int ptr.

Comment: @H2C03 your example is perfectly fine, except that you have to change `int arr[2][3]` to `int arr[3][2]` to match it with the initializer list

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the value of your matrix using the address(what you called location), but you have to calculate the right offset from the start. The offset calculation should be something like this :

```
(matrix_x_len * Y + X) * sizeof(unsigned int) + offset to the beggining of the matrix
```

then when you have the offset you can change mat like this : `*(val + offset) = new_value`.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur It's contiguous in memory.

Comment: the matrix is stored as a continuous sequence of 192 bytes starting at location `mat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course modify the bits since `unsigned char mat[24][8]` gives you a memory chunk with 24*8*sizeof(char) bytes.
(I assume that unsigned char is 1 byte (=8 bits) in size and unsigned int is 4 Bytes (=32 bits) from here but this may be dependant on your system.

But accessing memory elements of 1 byte width using a pointer to elements with 4 bytes width is tricky and can easily produce errors.

If you set element 0 of the int array to 1 for example

```
#define ROWS 24
#define COLS 8

unsigned char mat[ROWS][COLS];
unsigned int * val = (unsigned int*)&mat;

val[0] = 1;
```

You will see that mat[0][0] is 0, mat[0][1] is 0, mat[0][2] is 0 and mat[0][3] is 1.

Please not that you cannot edit the elements of mat directly using their offset in memory via such a "miss-typed" pointer.
Accessing `val[10*8+4]` for example will access byte 336 from the beginning of your memory chunk which has only 192 bytes.

You will have to calculate your index correctly:

```
size_t byte_index = (10*COLS+4)*sizeof(unsigned char); // will be 84
size_t int_index = byte_index / sizeof(unsigned int); // will be 21
size_t sub_byte = byte_index%sizeof(unsigned int); // will be 0
```

Therefore you can access `val[int_index]` or `val[21]` to access the 4 bytes that contain the data of element mat[10][4] which is byte number `sub_byte` of the refered unsigned int value.

If you have the same types there is no problem except that you need to calculate the correct offset.

```
#define ROWS 24
#define COLS 8

unsigned char mat[ROWS][COLS];
unsigned char * val = &mat;

val[10*8+4] = 12; // set mat[10][4] to 12
*(val+10*8+5) = 13; // set mat[10][5] to 13
```

Answer (score 0):

can do it but making val as *unsigned char**

val = &mat;

will make easy to do modification of bits